# How do I show a dynamically-generated menu in the _SiteLayout.cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to show database content on `_layout.cshtml`?

I have `menu` and `roleMenu` tables, and I want show different a menu based on database records.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `IconUrl` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `ActionUrl` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `ParentMenuId` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hide` boolean not null DEFAULT False,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_menu_menu` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentMenuId`) REFERENCES `menu` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this article by Sumit Maitra: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=811

I think, it will help you in achieving what you are looking for